# Multiple checkbox values are saved but not loaded in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, checkbox

My app has merchants that can accept 3 methods of payment. In order to create / edit the records I am using multiple checkboxes in a form and an array field in PostgreSQL

The funny thing is that it works fine when saving the values, both when creating and updating. The array is saved fine to the PG table as an array based on the checkboxes values. However, when editing, the edit form DOES NOT load the correct values from the database. All the checkboxes always appear unchecked, disregarding the array values in the PG table. The same thing happens when creating even though the migration sets the default values as all checkboxes supposedly checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Shared view partial for create and edit:

```
= form_for @merchant, layout: :horizontal do |f|
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Credit Card', nil
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Paypal', nil
  = f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true }, 'Direct Deposit', nil
  = f.submit 'Save Changes', :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

My controller code is:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_merchant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
    @merchants = Merchant.all
  end 

  def show
  end 

  def new 
    @merchant = Merchant.new
  end 

  def edit
  end 

  def create
    @merchant = Merchant.new(merchant_params)
    @merchant.save
    respond_with(@merchant)
  end 

  def update
    @merchant.update(merchant_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Merchant was successfully updated.'
    respond_with(@merchant)
  end 

  def destroy
    @merchant.destroy
    redirect_to merchants_url, notice: 'Merchant was successfully destroyed.'
  end 

  private
    def set_merchant
      @merchant = Merchant.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def merchant_params
      params.require(:merchant).permit(:name, :description, :notif_email, :category_id, :country_id, :costo_procesamiento, payment_accepted:[]) 
    end 
end
```

And my migration:

```
class CreateMerchants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :merchants do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.text :default_terms
      t.text :notif_email
      t.boolean :visible, default: true
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :country_id
      t.integer :costo_procesamiento, null:false, default: 0
      t.string :payment_accepted, array: true, default: "['Credit Card','Paypal','Direct Deposit']"
      t.references :country, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because while the checkboxes know there are multiple values, they don't know which is which (they can't go off the checked/unchecked values). Change your checkboxes so they know when they should or shouldn't be checked:

```
= f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true, checked: @payments.include?('Credit Card')}, 'Credit Card', nil
= f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true, checked: @payments.include?('Paypal') }, 'Paypal', nil
= f.check_box :payment_accepted, { :multiple => true, checked: @payments.include?('Direct Deposit') }, 'Direct Deposit', nil
```

and in your controller, add:

```
def edit
  @payments = @merchant.payment_accepted
end
```

Comment: This made my day ! I needed `checked` attr